# When $x(t)$ and the output $y(t)$ are related by linear differential equations, why is the system unstable when $M>N$?

Tags: linear-systems, differential-equation

This is two linear differential systems equating each other.
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^Ny(t)}{dt^N}+a_1\frac{d^{N-1}y(t)}{dt^{N-1}}+\cdots+a_{N-1}\frac{dy(t)}{dt}+a_Ny(t)=\\
b_{N-M}\frac{d^Mx(t)}{dt^M}+b_{N-M+1}\frac{d^{M-1}x(t)}{dt^{M-1}}+\cdots+b_{N-1}\frac{dx(t)}{dt}+b_Nx(t)
\end{equation}

In the textbook, it states that "theoretically the powers $M$ and $N$ in the foregoing equations can take on any value. However, practical considerations make $M>N$ undesirable for two reasons." One of the reasons being, the equation acts as "$(M − N)$th-order differentiator" - to which I am confused why.

The textbook further explains that "A differentiator
represents an unstable system because a bounded input like the step input results in an unbounded
output, $\delta(t)$".

Comment: But the textbook (Lathi's *Linear systems and signals*) also refers to a Section in Chapter 4 where it is shown why the system acts as an $(M-N)^{th}$-order differentiator. Have you read that section? If so, please clarify your question explaining what it is that you don't understand in that explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try the simple $N=0$ and $M=1$ case:

$$a_0 y(t) = b_0 \frac{d x(t)}{ dt} + b_1 x(t) \tag{1}$$

Now, let's think about stability.  A standard approach to stability is that for any bounded (finite-valued) input, we want a bounded output. This is called bounded-input, bounded-output or BIBO stability.

So then a unit step $u(t)$ input to (1) will give an output that includes the term
$$b_0 \delta(t)$$
where $\delta$ is the [Dirac delta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), which is unbounded.

So, even though our input (a unit step) is bounded (it has a maximum value of 1), it yields an output that is unbounded.

So the system is not BIBO stable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is very clear in this simple case why BI -> BO. I guess I am more so confused on why M = N would be stable (or even N > M). Is it because we are able to anti differentiate both sides respect to t? Thank you for you time.

Comment: That is a _separate question_, but yes, it's because when we write a differential equation like $x'(t) = a x(t) + u(t)$, the actual physical process is more like $x(t) = \int a x(t) + u(t) dt$.

Comment: Thank you. I'll make sure to post a separate question in the future.